# POWERSHELL: Defrag Script Fails to Analyze

Tags: powershell-4.0

When I try to run this script I keep getting errors indicating the defrag portion fails to run: "Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'DefragAnalysis'."

```
$drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |Where { $_.drivetype -eq '3' -and $_.driveletter} |Select-Object driveletter
#|select driveletter="C:\"

foreach($drive in $drives)
{
$report = $drive.DefragAnalysis()
$report.DefragAnalysis
}
```

So what am I missing?
I get this error in PS 4.0 and 5.1:
PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018

Answer (score 0):

...and wouldn't you know I found the solution on Petri.com:

```
$Servers = Get-Content d:\batch\input\servers.txt
ForEach ($Server in $Servers){
$analysis = Get-DefragAnalysis -Driveletter C: -Computername $Server
}
```